# Is there any good way to convert TAC to x86-64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86-64

For example, I want to convert a TAC `add c a b` (means `c := a + b`) to x86 assembly. For simplicity, assume `a, b, c` are all registers. But x86 only has `ADD a b` that means `a += b`.

My idea is first move `0` to `c`, then do `ADD c a` and `ADD c b`. However, I convert one TAC into three assembly statements, while in MIPS I only need one line `add c a b`.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Use `lea c, [a+b]`, but remember that on x86 the shortest code isn't necessarily the fastest. Also, you can of course do `mov c, a; add c, b` you don't need 3 instructions. PS: `lea` doesn't set flags so if you need that, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fix it earlier, in the TAC.

There are two main techniques I know, the first is simple rewriting everything like this:

```
xor c a b
```

Into this:

```
copy c a
xor c c b
```

That's basically as you described:

> My idea is first move 0 to c, then do ADD c a and ADD c b

But at the TAC level, and copy instead of zero/add, zero/add is weird.

Now if you run the register allocator all 2-operand constraints are automatically satisfied. Of course any self-copy ends up as zero instructions, and you can make the register allocator prefer to arrange for that by attempting to coalesce the virtual registers of a copy. The majority of the copies will be avoided.

An other technique is to do basically the same thing, but insert the copies lazily after failing to coalesce the first time the register allocator is run. It's a bit of a trade-off depending on how your register allocator works. It prevents the almost-doubling of your TAC size (and then relying on instruction selection to ignore most copies), but runs the register allocator twice. Whether that's slower or faster depends mostly on how the register allocator works.

You can do it implicitly, by trying to coalesce a source and dest of operations that have the 2-operand constraint, accepting it if it fails, and then have the instruction selector have different cases for if the constraint was satisfied or not. That basically pushes the complexity into the instruction selector, which is already bad enough so I would not prefer to do it.

I've changed the operation to `xor` because `add` has a 3-operand version on x86, `lea` - unless you need the flags, in which case you can of course still do the copy/preferentially-coalesce thing.